# Divide Ids into multiple groups based on a number in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, divide, group

I'm trying to divide records of data into groups.

Each group size has 4 records, and the last group maybe less than 4,
with numbering rows in each group, and count Ids in each group.

The final result should be like this

[image: Final Result]

I tried something like this

```
declare @t int 
set @t = (select count(*) from mytable) 

declare @s int 
set @s = 4

select 
    t.Id
    ,@s over (order by t.Id asc) as GroupId 
    ,case when (row_number() over (order by t.Id asc ) %@s ) = 0 then 4 else (row_number() over (order by t.Id asc) %@s ) end  as RowNum
    ,(count Ids in each group) IdCount
from
    mytable t
group by 
    t.Id
order by 
    t.Id asc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)` function divided by 4 to define the id groups as the following (If you don't have duplicates in ID):

```
WITH IdGroups AS
(
  SELECT ID,
         CEILING(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) *1.0/4) GRP
  FROM table_name
)
SELECT ID, GRP AS GroupID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GRP ORDER BY ID) AS ROWNUM, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY GRP) AS IDCount
FROM IdGroups
ORDER BY ID
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/joXQLRVh).

If you have repeated IDs and you want to count repeated Ids as 1 record, and give them the same row number (same rank), you may use `DENSE_RANK` function instead of `ROW_NUMBER`.

```
WITH IdGroups AS
(
  SELECT ID,
         CEILING(DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID) *1.0/4) GRP
  FROM table_name
)
SELECT ID, GRP AS GroupID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GRP ORDER BY ID) AS ROWNUM, 
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION by GRP ORDER BY ID) 
      + DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY GRP ORDER BY ID DESC) 
      - 1 AS IDCount
FROM IdGroups
ORDER BY ID
```

Check this [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/B70GUasG).

Comment: Many thanks Ahmed, This is just what I wanted.

Comment: But RowNum is not numbering each group individually

Comment: I already fixed that, check the updated answer.

Comment: It's better to use row_number function than dense_rank, especially if there are duplicates in the id column. I updated the answer according to this. Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Comment: Honestly I needed this update, but if the IDs were repeated the RowNum and IdCount doesn't work functionally,

What if I want to count repeated Ids as 1 record, and give them the same Row number? How to do that?

Comment: As same as GroupId doesn't work as expected in this update .. some Ids separated on 2 groups

Comment: if you want to count repeated Ids as 1 record, and give them the same row number, (the same group also) you may use DESNS_RANK, I updated the answer.

Comment: Just use integer division.

Comment: Ok, DESNS_RANK solved the problem,  but IDCount doesn't count as expected.

Comment: I used DESNS_RANK on GRP in WITH, and on ROWNUM to get what i want , but IDCount doesn't count as expected. How can i fix it?

Comment: What it should be in this case, do you want to count distinct IDs, i.e. in the provided demo where all IDs =1, the IDCount  should be 1 ?

Comment: @shawnt00, yes way may use integer division without ceiling and the groups can be defined as `(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)-1)/4 GRP`

Comment: The IDCount should count repeated Ids as 1 not as many as repeated.

Comment: @Abohy Your sample data doesn't give any indication there would be repeated identifiers.

Comment: Yes shawnt00, Ahmed answer was solved the issue that was presented, and helped me .. But i faced repeated Ids in another query, So how to solve repeated Ids as the sample .. Thanks in advance

Comment: I updated the answer to count distinct ID values, kindly, check and update me if that's OK

Comment: Just to improve the code, it must use DENSE_RANK() with ROWNUM to give repeated Ids the same row number (same rank)